# I'm confused by Ruby notation

Tags: ruby

What's the difference between

```
:anyName
```

and

```
anyName:
```

I don't know when I must type `:` before a variable name and when I must type it after. Can anyone explain that?

Comment: Yes, I agree. It's really duplicated. But, I don't know why, I didn't thinked in the word 'colom' to search. I did my search with 'notation' and variations of this word.